# Expanding an inline element to its auto width

Tags: jquery, css

I have a situation where I have a button, and an object after it. Initially the object is width 0. The idea is that when the button is clicked, it expands to its "exact width".

The text can be of different lengths. All I know is that it will never take more than 1 line, so I shouldnt worry about wrapping.

I made a small mockup (not working, of course), of the situation im describing. Could someone please tell me how I could do this?

MOckup: http://codepen.io/dbugger/pen/HbyLr

JS Code that I want to adapt:

```
$(".handler").on("click", function(){

    if($(this).hasClass("open")){
        $(".elastic").animate({width:"0px"});
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    } else {
        // Here i cant animate to auto
        $(".elastic").animate({width:"auto"});
        // This works, but there is no animation...
        $(".elastic").css({width:"auto"});
        $(this).addClass("open");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is wrap the text on another element:

```
<div class="elastic">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, laboriosam.</div>
</div>
```

Then with CSS change the `display` property so you can get the width val.

```
.elastic div {
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

And with jQuery take that value as a `var`

```
else {
   var siz = $(this).next('.elastic').find('div').width();
   $(".elastic").animate({width:siz});
   $(this).addClass("open");
}
```

Check this **[Demo Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/unwqE)**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate to `auto` lengths (at least with jQuery animation).

What you may consider doing is putting a container around it:

```
<div class="elasticContainer">
    <span class="elastic">Some text here</span>
</div>
```

Set the CSS of the container to prevent `overflow`:

```
.elasticContainer {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
]
```

Then in your jQuery, you can get the length of the `span` and animate to that:

```
var $elastic = $(.elastic),
    $elasticContainer = $elastic.parent(),
    elasticWidth = $elastic.width();

$elasticContainer.width(0);

$('.handler').on('click',function(){
    var $self = $(this);

    if($self.hasClass('open')){
        $elasticContainer
            .stop()
            .animate({
                width:elasticWidth
            });
    } else {
        $elasticContainer
            .stop()
            .animate({
                width:0
            });
    }
});
```

This should provide a single, clean transition that will show / hide as you wish (I think).

If you have many different boxes for elastic, you'll need to get the width on the fly:

```
var $elasticContainers = $(.elastic).parent();

$elasticContainers.width(0);

$('.handler').on('click',function(){
    var $self = $(this),
        $nextElasticContainer = $self.nextUntil('.elasticContainer');

    if($self.hasClass('open')){
        $nextElasticContainer
            .stop()
            .animate({
                width:($nextElasticContainer.find('.elastic').width())
            });
    } else {
        $nextElasticContainer
            .stop()
            .animate({
                width:0
            });
    }
});
```

Which should be dynamic enough.

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately can't animate to an `auto` value (at least that's the case with CSS and I believe the `animate` method in jQuery behaves very similarly).

However, you can animate using `min-width` or `max-width` and setting the value to a definite pixel value. Here's an example that's working using a defined `max-width`:

```
$(".handler").on("click", function(){

  if($(this).hasClass("open")){
    $(".elastic").animate({"min-width":"0px", "width": "0px"});
    $(this).removeClass("open");
  } else {
    $(".elastic").animate({"width":"auto", "min-width":"500px"});
    $(this).addClass("open");
  }

});
```